# Perl: Web Server's Directory Listing

Tags: perl, url, directory, server, lwp-useragent

Is there any possible way of crawling web server directories and display the files in it ?

I found a way to list all the files in a local disk directory.

Here's the Directory Listing code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $dir = '/home/srikanth/Documents/';
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
  next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
  print "$file\n";
}
closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

So, is there a way to list the web server's files upon giving URL ?

I have tried using `LWP::Simple` and `LWP::UserAgent` but could not find the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Since Stackoverflow considers that answer to be too short, no.

A web server can be configured to provide a directory listing, or may support [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), but there isn't necessarily a connection between a URL and a file system directory on a web server.